# iBeacon ranging through a wall

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ibeacon, rssi

I have been testing some beacons (for an iOS app i'm writing) , and have the odd situation (for me anyway..) that a beacon on the other side of a wall has a stronger RSSI than on the side of the wall where my iPad is!

I asked the company's support and they said that a wall's construction can help to amplify such a signal, but that they had no reference material concerning this.

I have been trying to find some reference information about this, but am not having much luck.

Has anybody had similar experiences, or can explain the amplification issue?

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: Not really an SO question, but the signal could be reflected off metalwork in the wall to 'increase' or 'reduce' the signal strength. The battery / broadcast power could also have an impact. I wouldn't say ranging is an exact science as a lot of things can have an impact.

Comment: Orientation of the beacon is another factor (beacon transmitters are far from uniformly transmit in all directions, because of the shape of the antenna and of absorption of the internal components). I agree that metalwork can affect signal in both good and bad ways.